# how to display helm revision number

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

How to display helm revision number so that it can be used in tagging.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overlow! Can you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried so far? We're here to help you solve a problem, not code for you :)

Comment: helm history app-name?

Comment: That will give all the details with revision status chart and description .., but I want to take only the last deployed revision number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Helm also defines [several built-in objects](https://docs.helm.sh/chart_template_guide/#built-in-objects) that can be referenced from your template.  You can reference `.Release.Revision` in a template to get the current chart revision being deployed.  Note that this number resets if you `helm delete --purge` a chart.